# Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop. Error occurs while trying to run 'make vstart' command

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to run `make` command but showing up the above error. And also tried to run `make vstart`. And I think the indentation was also correct. And it showing a warning along with the above error: `Makefile:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored.` Can anyone please help me out? Thanks!

```
# A sample Makefile for building both Google Mock and Google Test and
# using them in user tests.  This file is self-contained, so you don't
# need to use the Makefile in Google Test's source tree.  Please tweak
# it to suit your environment and project.  You may want to move it to
# your project's root directory.
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#
#   make [all]  - makes everything.
#   make TARGET - makes the given target.
#   make clean  - removes all files generated by make.

# Please tweak the following variable definitions as needed by your
# project, except GMOCK_HEADERS and GTEST_HEADERS, which you can use
# in your own targets but shouldn't modify.

# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file, or if you want to use
# a copy of Google Test at a different location.
GTEST_DIR = ../../googletest

# Points to the root of Google Mock, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GMOCK_DIR = ..

# Where to find user code.
USER_DIR = ../test

# Flags passed to the preprocessor.
# Set Google Test and Google Mock's header directories as system
# directories, such that the compiler doesn't generate warnings in
# these headers.
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include -isystem $(GMOCK_DIR)/include

# Flags passed to the C++ compiler.
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
# created to the list.
TESTS = gmock_test

# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
                $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# All Google Mock headers. Note that all Google Test headers are
# included here too, as they are #included by Google Mock headers.
# Usually you shouldn't change this definition. 
GMOCK_HEADERS = $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/*.h \
                $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/internal/*.h \
                $(GTEST_HEADERS)

# House-keeping build targets.

all : $(TESTS)

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) gmock.a gmock_main.a *.o

# Builds gmock.a and gmock_main.a.  These libraries contain both
# Google Mock and Google Test.  A test should link with either gmock.a
# or gmock_main.a, depending on whether it defines its own main()
# function.  It's fine if your test only uses features from Google
# Test (and not Google Mock).

# Usually you shouldn't tweak such internal variables, indicated by a
# trailing _.
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)
GMOCK_SRCS_ = $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GMOCK_HEADERS)

# For simplicity and to avoid depending on implementation details of
# Google Mock and Google Test, the dependencies specified below are
# conservative and not optimized.  This is fine as Google Mock and
# Google Test compile fast and for ordinary users their source rarely
# changes.
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gmock-all.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock-all.cc

gmock_main.o : $(GMOCK_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) -I$(GMOCK_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) \
            -c $(GMOCK_DIR)/src/gmock_main.cc

gmock.a : gmock-all.o gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gmock_main.a : gmock-all.o gtest-all.o gmock_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

# Builds a sample test.

gmock_test.o : $(USER_DIR)/gmock_test.cc $(GMOCK_HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(USER_DIR)/gmock_test.cc

gmock_test : gmock_test.o gmock_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Comment: That typically happens when you use *space* instead of *tab* for the indentation. Make sure your editor save makefiles with tab, and don't replace them with spaces.

Comment: can u elaborate?

Comment: You see the rule for `clean`? That contains a single `rm` command, and the command is indented a bit. That indentation *must* be a tab-character, it can't be e.g. four spaces. It's the same for *all* indentations, the first "space" must always be a tab.

Comment: @MounikaSmitha the comment was pretty clear: it's a well know fact that the rule lines in the Makefiles have to start with a `TAB`. Some editors replace the tabs with spaces, to you it looks the same, but not `make`. So it will complain.

Comment: The fact that you're seeing these issues in line 1 of the makefile (`Makefile:1:` means line 1 of the file `Makefile`) means that your problem is *not* related to TAB characters vs. spaces so you can ignore that.  Most likely you have some bogus characters at the start of your makefile.  Maybe you have a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of your file.  What version of GNU make are you using (`make --version`)?  Older versions don't recognize BOMs.  Try running `od -a -N 80 Makefile` or similar and see if you have any weird ASCII characters show up.

Comment: Make version is 3.81. Yeah I found something like this:    0000000    b   o   o   k nul nul nul nul   m   a   r   k nul nul nul nul
0000020    8 nul nul nul   8 nul nul nul dc4 eot nul nul nul nul eot dle
0000040  nul nul nul nul   r   s   /   m   :   ;   m   Q   ?  ht   ?   A
0000060  nul nul nul nul   /   c   e   p   ? stx nul nul eot nul nul nul
0000100  etx etx nul nul nul eot nul nul enq nul nul nul soh soh nul nul
0000120

Comment: @pablo I gave tab space in front of each and every line, but gives the same error.

Comment: @MounikaSmitha which editor are you using? Try looking into the settings and deactivate UTF-8 BOM, so that the BOM is not written in the file.

Comment: As I said before, your problem has absolutely nothing to do with tabs or spaces.  Forget that.  The problem is that the makefile you've showed us here is in no way related to the makefile that you are actually using, based on the output of `od`.  That's why make is failing.  What is the name of the file you have pasted into this question?  What is the command you're using to invoke make?